# POST method not working, returning null

Tags: php, post

need help with stupid doubt but that i have no clue about.

Trying to pass thru POST from a webpage to another (volunteer.php to confirmdata.php), but the problem is that i always get null.

**volunteer.php:**

```
<form action="confirmdata.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
                  <fieldset>
                    <table width="415" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="108">Name:</td>
                        <td width="301"><label for="nome"></label>
                        <input name="nome" type="text" class="bgverdinho" id="nome" /></td>
                      </tr>
        </table></fieldset></form>
```

**Now on confirmdata.php:**

```
  <li> <?php echo  "Nome ".$nome  = empty($_POST['nome'])  ? null : $_POST['nome']; ?></li>
```

And nothing, it return null but why, doesnt it save 'nome' in the POST variable?

thanks guys

Comment: Are you running this through apache or nginx or something?

Comment: What is the result you get? In order to work with PHP, you **should** install a PHP server like Apache to process the pages.

Comment: Try getting rid of enctype="multipart/form-data" .  I've seen this cause problems for some people, and it's really not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**(updated)**

Please try:

```
echo  "Nome ".( empty($_POST['nome'])  ? null : $_POST['nome']);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: A blank input field sent via POST will come through as a blank string, though, which isset would evaluate as True.  I think he's got it right with empty...

Comment: Ok, sorry, it could be too narrow - I'm correcting and thx for sharing your opinion

Answer (score 0):

try this at your confirmdata.php

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
   echo "Sorry form hasn't been submitted";
}else{
   if(empty($_POST['nome'])){    
       echo "No value has been submitted";
  }else{
     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     echo $nome;
  }
}
```

Comment: tried this and the result is "Sorry form hasn't been submitted".

Comment: That means the form hasn't been submitted, one reason, you dont seem to have a submit button inside your form tags, if you do make sure the "name" for the submit button is "submit".
Another reason is is your action linking correctly to confirmdata.php, if both reasons are true than it should echo out something positive.

Answer (score 0):

guys i had the onclick function in the submit button. after i erased it the post method worked. as i said i'm using xampp.

Do you have any ideia why this happens? shouldn't the onClick not afect php?

thnx for the answers